# When assert() fails, what is the program exit code?

Tags: c, linux, assert

When an [`assert()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/assert.3.html) call fails, what is the exit code used, and where is it documented?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The C99 (unchanged in C11) standard states that `assert` calls `abort` and the `abort` stuff states this about the return code:

> An implementation-defined form of the status unsuccessful termination is returned to the host environment by means of the function call `raise(SIGABRT)`.

It's documented in section 7.2.1.1 (assert) and 7.20.4.1 (abort) of the C99 standard [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

Many UNIX systems will return 128 plus the signal number (`SIGABRT` is signal number 6) so you may get 134. Whatever you get, it should be documented by the C implementation.

For example, see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/gcc/index.html#toc_C-Implementation) for `gcc`. Although it's quite silent on what gets returned to the calling environment. From the specific sections [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/gcc/C-Implementation.html#C-Implementation):

> Some choices are made by the library and operating system (or other environment when compiling for a freestanding environment); refer to their documentation for details.

And [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/gcc/Library-functions-implementation.html#Library-functions-implementation):

> The behavior of most of these points are dependent on the implementation of the C library, and are not defined by GCC itself.

So is the `glibc` doco [here](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Termination.html#Program-Termination) on program termination (specifically the exit status bit). It mentions conventions but no firm rules.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, and 134 is exactly what I am getting.

Comment: The linked to documentation for GCC doesn't appear to contain anything of interest, nor can I find the quote you've made.

Comment: You might change the glibc doco link to point directly to here unless I've missed something? http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html#Exit-Status

Comment: @Matt, they were links underneath that link I gave. I've added the specific links to the quotes. The link I gave is the top level which gives implementation details for quite a lot of GCC so it's still quite handy, allowing you to drill down to lots of different parts (c, c++, etc).

Comment: It also happened to be `134` for a [C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) / [.NET Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Core) console application on Linux: Failed `Trace.Assert()` in C# and `echo $?` in Bash. The most likely version of .NET Core was 3.1.21-1 (though there is also ".NET Host" 6.0.1)). The Linux system was [Ubuntu MATE 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases)). The significant date for the build tools was approximately 2021-10 (one update behind). The signature for `Main()` was `static void Main(string[] args)`.

Answer (score 3):

It's implementation-specific.  You could do this:

```
int main()
{
    assert(0);
}
```

Then run it:

```
./a.out
echo $?
```

> 1 (<- or whatever)

This'll at least tell you what to expect for your setup.  I'm getting *134* on a couple of Linux boxes with both [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) and g++.

Comment: You should always back your answers with a specific reference to the standard.

Comment: Compilers don't always follow the standard to the T. (I'm looking at you Microsoft) While it is good to know what the standard says - it's also equally as good to know what compilers really do. What they should do isn't always what they actually do. That and the standard isn't actually free.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the actual spec for it (POSIX is kind of hard to search), but I did find a reference.

A thrown assertion results in an exit status that is the same as whatever `EXIT_FAILURE` expands to be ([reference](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdlib.h.html)). Since you are dealing with Linux, you are also dealing with POSIX, which further defines the behavior from c99.

Answer (score -2):

I was working with [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) message queues, and I have got the same error, mq_open was failed with errono 38 (ENOSYS).

The workaround is to rebuild the kernel with POSIX MESSAGE QUEUE enabled in the kernel configuration.

This will build the kernel with POSIX message queue support and it worked for me.

Comment: I think you meant to put this answer on another question.

Comment: Identical to [the answer to *How do I stop sem_open() failing with ENOSYS?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270113/how-do-i-stop-sem-open-failing-with-enosys/2863471#2863471). The answer here was probably moved there (posted there about 10 minutes later).