# how to close a console application from inside loop with 2 switches

Tags: c#, while-loop, switch-statement, exit

i'm creating a simple calculator and i've been trying to use `switches` to allow the user to select whether they want to add, subtract, multiply or divide their inputted values.

They can also type quit to exit the console. but after case `quit`: when i add a method of closing the console such as `Environment.Exit(-1);`

It throws up an error and using `break;` just brings me into my next switch (both of which are in the same while loop as the second one restarts the console).

Any ideas on what i can do?

```
            {
                case "add":
                    answer = (num1 + num2);
                    Console.WriteLine("your answer is {0:0.00}", answer);
                    break;
                case "subtract":
                    answer = (num1 - num2);
                    Console.WriteLine("your answer is {0:0.00}", answer);
                    break;
                case "multiply":
                    answer = (num1 * num2);
                    Console.WriteLine("your answer is {0:0.00}", answer);
                    break;
                case "divide":
                    answer = (num1 / num2);
                    Console.WriteLine("your answer is {0:0.00}", answer);
                    break;
                case "quit":

            }
```

Comment: you could `return` from the Main method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct Way to Exit From Console Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35393877/correct-way-to-exit-from-console-application)

Comment: What error do you get when you use _"Environment.Exit(-1); "_?

Comment: PaulF it tells me that control cannot fall out of switch from final case label (case "quit":)

Comment: It sounds like you are missing the break statement - required even though you are exiting the application. Also note - to tag someone in a comment, precede the name with @ - e.g. @PaulF - then they will be notified of your reply.

Comment: putting a break statement before the environment.exit causes it to skip over the environment.exit and into my next switch inside my while loop

Comment: It needs to go after : _"case "quit" : Environment.Exit(-1); break;"_

Comment: the break should be after the exit, obviously. also, you could just `return -1` from main, assuming this isn't in another method. by the way, from what we see this looks like a successful exit, so use exit code 0 @JackMcCann

Comment: ahhh makes sense

Comment: works perfectly now. i'll add that info as the answer

Comment: For future reference - when asking a question - rather than saying some piece of code "threw up an error" you should be more explicit. If it threw an exception - then give full details of the exception. If, as in this case, it was a compiler error, then give details of that. You will get the correct answer much quicker. Also, show the exact failing code, not the edited version.

Comment: i'll be sure to do that in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i just needed to place a break statement after environment.exit(-1) instead of beforehand

```
case "quit":
    Environment.Exit(-1);
    break;
```