# Terminate console application during execution in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

how to stop the console application during execution through taking any specific input from user like if we ask him that press Y to exit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286056/what-is-the-command-for-exit-an-console-application-on-c

Comment: Pretty unclear why your user needs help to exit your program.  He can press Ctrl+C or click the close button.  Bam, gone.  No point in giving him a 3rd option and forcing him to type N repeatedly.

Comment: dear problem is solved now.. and think why the 3rd way is created that i found... these are created to use

Answer (score 3):

Try This:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter Y to Exit");
String strInput=Console.ReadLine();
if(strInput.Equals("Y"))
{
   Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to look in the direction of `Console.ReadKey()`. This will block the executing thread until input has been received.

For more information see this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: `Console.KeyAvailable` MSDN help already contains an example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.keyavailable(v=vs.100).aspx