# Gracefully close a programmatically launched console app

Tags: c#, process, console-application

I am working on a simple UI for the [ccminer](https://github.com/tpruvot/ccminer/releases). As part of my launch/shutdown I use something like this to launch the ccminer.exe:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = “ccminer.exe”
info.Arguments = "start";
info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
Process.Start(info);
```

When I need to stop it I just call kill(). Now, the problem is that this way, half of the time the console app crashes my video driver and does not gracefully shutdown.

If I were to run ccminer as a console app, I would hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and then it would ask something like: “Terminate, Y/N?” and upon receiving a confirmation - gracefully halt without crashing the video driver.

Is there a way I can programmatically mimic this graceful <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> shutdown without simply killing my process?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15281070/21567) might do want you want.

Comment: You should use Environment.Exit(0); https://stackoverflow.com/a/10286091/7810515

Comment: @DrewSumido This terminates a console application from its own code, yes. But that is not what's being asked here.

Comment: "Graceful" is not an option when a console mode app can crash a video driver.  You need to get the computer fixed.

Comment: @HansPassant ccminer works directly with the video driver, so halting it without a proper interrupt and resources release inevitably causes a video driver crash

Comment: Process.Kill() is not fundamentally different from pressing Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Break.  If Ctrl+C does not cause a crash then consider to pinvoke GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent().  If it does then you'll have to make it graceful by allowing the user to easily stop the program with, say, the Escape key.