# Why does spawned program exit code change when debugging?

Tags: c++, c, linux, assert, exit-code

I have a C++ program that I'm using to test that another program doesn't crash. The parent code(we'll call it 'parentProg') looks something like this:

```
int run(const char * command)
{
  ...

  int retCode = system(command);
  printf("Code is %d\n",retCode);
  if(retCode == 134) //128 + SIGABORT
  {
    // Record error conditions
    ...
  }
}
```

The command variable contains the program being tested(we'll call it 'childProg'). With a previous Linux distribution, this code worked as expected. If a.out crashed or hit an assertion, it would return 134 and the error handling code would run. However after I upgraded to a newer Linux distribution this is no longer the case. Instead I see a return code of 6 when run as a spawned program, using GDB, or nemiver. Strangely, it reverts back to 134 if I run the child program alone, or using DDD.

For the following tests I've modified childProg to be only the following code:

```
#include <assert.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  assert(0);
  return 0;
}
```

childProg by itself

```
[user@localhost multi]$ ./childProg 
childProg: temp.cpp:5: int main(int, char **): Assertion `0' failed.
Abort
[user@localhost multi]$ echo $?
134
```

parentProg which spawns childProg

```
[user@localhost multi]$ ./parentProg 1 o
Running 1 times
childProg: temp.cpp:5: int main(int, char **): Assertion `0' failed.
Code is 6
Done 0
[user@localhost multi]$
```

With GDB

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: parentProg 1 o
Running 1 times
Detaching after fork from child process 3311.
childProg: temp.cpp:5: int main(int, char **): Assertion `0' failed.
Code is 6
Done 0
[Inferior 1 (process 3295) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

With DDD

```
(gdb) run 1 o
Starting program: parentProg 1 o
Running 1 times
Detaching after fork from child process 3336.
childProg: temp.cpp:5: int main(int, char **): Assertion `0' failed.
Code is 134
Done 0
[Inferior 1 (process 3319) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

This works as expected

```
[me@localhost multi]$ /bin/sh -c ./childProg
childProg: temp.cpp:5: int main(int, char **): Assertion `0' failed.
Abort
[me@localhost multi]$ echo $?
134
```

What could possibly be going on here? Is there a better way to check for crashing/segfaults/assertions other than checking the exit code?

Comment: Just to be clear, when the program is being debugged, if it generates a core dump, then the return value is ORed with 128 i.e. WCOREDUMP. This flag is **NOT** implemented on all versions of all variants of UNIX. Greg's code snippet should do the trick for you as the `WEXITSTATUS()` macro ignores everything but the lowest 8bits that contain the error code, in your case `6`.

Comment: @Adam12 It appears that in GDB the code is 6 because that has the 128 subtracted.  In DDD the 128 is not subtracted and the code is 134.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The <sys/wait.h> header file contains macros for analyzing return codes.

To check the reason for exit, you can do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

...

void run(const char *command)
{
    int retcode = system(command);

    if (WIFEXITED(retcode))
    {
        int status = WEXITSTATUS(retcode);
        if (status)
        {
            printf("Exited normally with FAILURE status of %d!\n", status);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Exited normally with SUCCESS(0) status!\n");
        }
    }
    else if (WIFSIGNALED(retcode))
    {
        int signal = WTERMSIG(retcode);
        printf("Abnormal termination - program crashed or was aborted with signal %d\n", signal);
    }

}
```

See "man waitpid" for a description of these macros.

Comment: Thanks. This code works reliably. I was testing for 134 based on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862731/when-assert-fails-what-is-the-program-exit-code/2862759#2862759).

Answer (score 1):

`(134 = 6 | __WCOREFLAG)`

See `man 2 wait`