# The second wstatus value is filled with 11 or 139 when using waitpid() function

Tags: c

As I know, the 11 means segment fault. but I don't exactly know why there is the 139 value for the segment fault. In my case, usually received 139 but sometimes the value is 11. please explain to me the reason.

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: “If status is not NULL, wait() and waitpid() store status information in the int to which it points. _This integer can be inspected with the following macros_..” - https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid

Comment: `139` is `0x8B` As above, see `man waitpid` for the `W*` helper macros. Try: `if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) printf("Signal is: %d\n",WTERMSIG(status));` In `status`, bit 7 (i.e. `0x80`) is set to indicate termination by a signal. And, the actual signal number is the lower 7 bits. So `WTERMSIG(status)` is `status & 0x7F` And, remember, `11` is `0x0B` in hex.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862731/when-assert-fails-what-is-the-program-exit-code/2862759#2862759 : `128 + 11 = 139`.